# Dual Booting: Is it possible for the boot partition for 2 separate OSes be on the same SSD, while the rest of each OS are each on a separate drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

For a clearer explanation of what I want to do:

(I'm relatively new to Linux and have near zero computing knowledge, so bear with me if I'm not using the right terms)

I have 2 SSDs, one older SATA one and a newer NVMe one which I just bought. Currently, I have POP OS installed and running on the older SSD. I also just installed Windows 10 on the new SSD. However, on second thought, I intend to use POP OS as my daily driver, and Windows more for gaming/other software compatibility.

With that in consideration, I would want to have POP OS running on my newer NVME SSD. To do that, I would have to clone POP OS over to the new NVME SSD and vice versa (Windows to the older one). However, I'm aware that such a process would not only be risky due to possibility of data loss, but also its gonna be a huge hassle, since I would first have to ideally backup both OSes on a third external hard drive.

Another problem is dual booting: I'm aware that for most other Linux distros, that wouldn't be a problem with GRUB. However, I'm aware that POP OS doesn't use GRUB as its bootloader (https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/b3rbaj/noob_at_installing_linux_grub_menu_not_showing_on/), and as of now, my PC boots directly into POP OS without a selection screen to choose which OS I want to boot into (without having to manually go into BIOS). I can't find a suitable guide for dual booting POP and Windows. There is one from the POP OS website itself: https://pop.system76.com/docs/dual-booting-windows/  however that involves erasing both drives and doing a clean installation, which as far as possible I want to avoid.

So tldr, my questions are:

1. Is it worth it to migrate POP OS (my daily driver) to my newer NVMe SSD (which already has Windows installed), risking data loss and the hassle of backing up and cloning both OSes, or does it really not matter that much that I would be 'wasting' my new NVMe drive on my non-daily driver OS.
2. How would I setup an automatic bootloader screen (like GRUB) to select which OS I want to boot into?

An idea I have is to simply move POP OS's boot partition/bootloader into the new NVME SSD and in some way 'combine' it with Windows bootloader, and put it at the top boot priority in the BIOS... if that is at all possible...

Any advice would be welcome and extremely appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea even if it's possible (which I think it is). Backup your data and reinstall the OSes, Windows first then Pop OS. You will save time and patience on trying to clone disks back and forth and eventually losing data.

Comment: @CaldeiraG thanks for the quick reply. I think that's a good idea. So I think what I should do is to first make a quick system backup/snapshot of each OS, save those snapshots on my third hard drive, then do a clean installation for both and hopefully restoring with the snapshots work. 

How about the GRUB, UEFI and dual booting thing? That's one thing I'm extremely unfamiliar with so any help would be great.

Comment: As I understand it, you are using systemd-boot which used to be gummi-boot. You may need to change timeout and add boot stanza. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459389/systemd-boot-skips-boot-menu-and-ignores-settings-in-loader-loader-conf